# Basic Fourier question

Tags: fourier-analysis

Calculate fourier transform for function $h$:

$$\hat{h}(\nu)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i2\pi\nu t} h(t) dt $$

When $h(t)=1$ and $|t|\le\frac 12$.

And when $h(t)=0$ and $|t|\gt\frac 12$

Also does it hold, that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{h}(\nu)|d\nu \lt \infty$? What about $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{h}(\nu)|^2d\nu \lt \infty$ or $\lim_{|\nu| \to \infty}\hat{h}(\nu)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sinc Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) is the fourier transform of a discrete pulse:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{h}(\nu)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t)e^{-2\pi i\nu t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}e^{-2\pi i\nu t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{e^{\pi i\nu}-e^{-\pi i\nu}}{2\pi i\nu}\\
&=\frac{\sin(\pi\nu)}{\pi\nu}\\[7pt]
&=\mathrm{sinc}(\pi\nu)
\end{align}
$$

---

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_k^{k+1}\left|\frac{\sin(\pi\nu)}{\pi\nu}\right|\,\mathrm{d}\nu
&\ge\int_k^{k+1}\left|\frac{\sin(\pi\nu)}{\pi(k+1)}\right|\,\mathrm{d}\nu\\
&=\frac2{\pi^2(k+1)}
\end{align}
$$
Since the [Harmonic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) diverges, the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\hat{h}(\nu)|\,\mathrm{d}\nu
$$
also diverges.

---

The [Plancherel Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) says that the $L^2$ norm of a function and its Fourier Transform are equal. Since
$$
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}1^2\,\mathrm{d}t=1
$$
we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\hat{h}(\nu)|^2\,\mathrm{d}\nu=1
$$

---

Since
$$
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}|1|\,\mathrm{d}t=1
$$
The [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) says that
$$
\lim_{\nu\to\infty}\hat{h}(\nu)=0
$$
Of course, since we've computed it, we can just see that
$$
\lim_{\nu\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi\nu)}{\pi\nu}=0
$$

Comment: The OP's struggling with pretty basic things (see comments) and you already gave it all chewed up...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I was hoping that the material could be understood, digested, and then they could move on. I don't think that these were homework problems, but I could be wrong. Other than pointing out the Plancherel Theorem and the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, the only work I did that was not already done, was to show that $\hat{h}\not\in L^1$.

Comment: it in fact looks like a homework problem to me, but probably a basic physics one, not mathematics.

Comment: @DonAntonio: fair enough. However, ELEC does not have a Physics.SE account (which does not invalidate your point).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it pretty straightforward, or am I missing something?:

$$\hat h(v)=\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}e^{-2\pi ivt}dt=\left.-\frac1{2\pi iv}e^{-2\pi ivt}\right|_{-1/2}^{1/2}=-\frac1{2\pi iv}\left(e^{-\pi iv}-e^{\pi iv}\right)=\frac1{\pi v}\sin\pi v$$

Comment: Why did the integral gap change from $-\infty \to \infty$ to $\frac{-1}{2} \to \frac 12$ ? I guess I don't understand the properties of the question..

Comment: Because $$h(t)=0\;\;\forall\,|t|>\frac12\implies e^{-2\pi ivt}h(t)=0\;\;\forall\,|t|>\frac12\;\;\ldots$$

Comment: That backwards A means "when" right? how does $h(t)=0$ when $|t|\gt\frac 12$?

Comment: No, it means "for all'", and $\;h(t)=0\;$ for $\;|t|>1/2\;$ is **your definition** !

Comment: AHHHH!! Thanks!! Got it ! :)

Comment: Hehe...a pleasure, @ELEC . Sometimes pretty basic things slip away in front of our own eyes.

Comment: But still one more question @DonAntonio :) we know $h(t)=1$ when $|t|\le\frac 12$ but why we use $-\frac 12$ as the lower gap and not $-\infty$ ?

Comment: Again, @Elec: because the function is zero in $\;(-\infty , -1/2)\;$ so its integral is zero there. Something similar happens with $\;(1/2,\infty)\;$ .  We're left only with the integral between $\;-1/2\;$ and $\;1/2\;$ because *only there* the function is non-zero.

Comment: But if it says the function is 1 when $t$ is less or equal to $1/2$ shouldn't it mean it's 1 for all $t$ values less than $1/2$. shouldn't it say $h(t)=1$ when $-1/2 \le t \le 1/2$

Comment: ELEC, what are you studying? The meaning of $\;|t|\le 1/2\;$ is **exactly** $\;-1/2\le t \le 1/2\;$ , when $\;t\in\Bbb R\;$ ...

Comment: Electrical engineering. Thanks!